# PHP 500 Error Contact Form?

Tags: php, contact-form

**I updated the code below based on answers**

Full disclosure I don't know PHP. I need a contact form and I understood this code below enough to feel comfortable using it. But when I try submitting the contact form I get an error: 
POST http://(myurlhere)/contact_form.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

I appreciate any insight. Below is the code:

HTML

```
        <form id="form">
          <p id="returnmessage"></p>
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
       </form>
       <a id="submit">Send</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.
// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
// if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $contact)) {
// echo "<span>* Please Fill Valid Contact No. *</span>";
} else {
$subject = $name;
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
. '<br/>I will be in touch soon.<br/><br/>'
. 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
. 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
. 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
. 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
. '<br/>'
. 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" .    $template . "</div>";
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
// Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
mail("myemailaddresshere@gmail.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "I will be in touch soon.";
}
} else {
echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
}
?>
```

**New Code** - It sends the message but does not have the name, email or message included in the email like it should.

**New HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
 <p id="returnmessage"></p>
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
 <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 <button id="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**New PHP**

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.
// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
// if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $contact)) {
// echo "<span>* Please Fill Valid Contact No. *</span>";
} else {
$subject = $name;
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
. '<br/>I will be in touch soon.<br/><br/>'
. 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
. 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
. 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
. 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
. '<br/>'
. 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" .    $template . "</div>";
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
// Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
mail("myemailhere@gmail.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "I will be in touch soon.";
}
?>
```

Comment: there is no action you mentioned the code. `<form id="form" action= "url.php">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is problem with the code you submitted. Some of the part i noticed there is a problem

form method and submit request to php not set, it has to be like this

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="php-url">
```

Submit link is added after ending `</form>` so this one has to be before form ends

```
 <button type"submit" id="submit">Send</a>
```

In your php file double } } added before else statement?

```
}
} else {
echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
```

The final html would be like

```
 <form id="form" method="post" action="submit.php">
      <p id="returnmessage"></p>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</a>
 </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.
$subject = $name;
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
$recipient = "myemailaddresshere@gmail.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
. '<br/>I will be in touch soon.<br/><br/>'
. 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
. 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
. 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
. 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
. '<br/>'
. 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" .    $template . "</div>";
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
// Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
mail($recipient, $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "I will be in touch soon.";
?>
```

Check the proof

[image]

Comment: Hey I tried using this but I've had no luck. I don't get the error anymore now that there's a "submit" button it seems but the message never goes through and I'm not seeing anything in the error logs. I'm completely PHP ignorant.

Comment: Also yes there is a double }} before the else - is this correct?

Comment: An update, I no longer have the error but it echoes "invalid email" as set in my code even if the email is valid.

Comment: Hey this finally sends thanks for that! But the emails received doesn't have the Name Email or Message. The Hello, is empty with no name and the 3 fields: Name: Email: and Message: are also blank in the email so I can't actually see any messages sent. I appreciate your help, this is the most progress I've had these last few days!

Comment: check the edits, this time it will work for sure. You haven't added name variable in form.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code has not changed anything in the emails received from the form. Still no name, e-mail address or message

Comment: have you replaced the <form > code as well and tested? I have changed <form>. code not php

Comment: check final edits. Just use both html form & php code as well. Change your email $recipient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120210/discussion-between-user5854648-and-sachin-g).

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems:

**1.** Change your form to add `name` attributes with the names that PHP expects.

**2.** Include a submit button to your form, and make sure it's actually inside the form (your `<a>Send</a>` is outside your form)

**3.** Change your form to use the `POST` instead of `GET` method because your PHP script is looking for values in `$_POST`

**4.** Since all your inputs are required to send a mail, add the `required` attribute to them

The form below makes all 4 adjustments

```
<form id="form" method="post">
  <p id="returnmessage"></p>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

You will also have to add an `action` attribute to `<form>` if the script that handles the submission is not the same file as the form.

**5.** On the PHP side, check that input is available before you attempt to use it. Right now your code proceeds with non-existent values if nothing was submitted

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['message'])){
    // proceed with your regular script here

}else{
    // no form values were submitted, so nothing to email
}
```

**6.** Find out where your server error log is and review it.  There may be more changes required beyond my steps. The details of a `500 error` can be found in the error log.

Comment: Adding the if was crucial thank you and I no longer have the error. However now it echoes the <span> tag of "invalid email" even if a valid email is entered so it does not send the message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

HTML code

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
   <p id="returnmessage"></p>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
  // Fetching Values from URL.
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.
  // After sanitization Validation is performed
  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   //check email validation and show error
  } else {
   //Email sending functionality
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send out any webmail from your server? 
Here is a php script, I call foolproof, it is very minimal and if it fails to send emails, then you may have some sort of web mail restriction.  This works on my shared server.  I'd also recommend checking your server logs.

```
<?php
function sanitize_my_email($field) {
$field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
$to_email = 'your-email@your-domain.com';
$subject = 'PHP Foolproof Send Mail script';
$message = 'This mail is sent using the foolproof PHP mail script';
$headers = 'From: gallienus@roman-empire.com';
//check if the email address is invalid $secure_check
$secure_check = sanitize_my_email($to_email);
if ($secure_check == false) {
echo "Invalid input";
}
else { //send email
mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "echo: This email is sent using simple foolproof PHP mail";
}
?>
```